# MassTransit MessageRequestClient timeout issue

Tags: masstransit

We have two services which exchange messages via MassTransit on top of RabbitMQ.
The goal is to send a message in a request/response way. Here's the code of the service which listens for a message, let's call it **Service1**:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(
    sbc =>
    {
        var host = sbc.Host(new Uri($"rabbitmq://{RabbitMqHost}"), h =>
        {
            h.ConfigureRabbitMq();//Custom extension to specify credentials
        });

        sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "CUSTOM_QUEUE_NAME", ep =>
        {
            ep.Exclusive = false;
            ep.AutoDelete = true;
            ep.Durable = false;
            ep.PrefetchCount = 1;
            ep.Handler<EngineStartingMessage>(async context =>
            {
                //SourceAddress and ResponseAddress are auto generated queues
                //Message processing is done here
                context.Respond(response);
            });
        });
    });
```

The code of the service which sends a message and process the result, let's call it **Service2**:

```
var requestClient =
        new MessageRequestClient<EngineStartingMessage, EngineStartingResponse>(
                EntityServiceBus,
                new Uri("CUSTOM_QUEUE_NAME?durable=false&autodelete=true&exclusive=false"),
                new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));

var engineStartResponse = requestClient.Request(new EngineStartingMessage() { Version = SystemVersion }).Result;
```

When I run the above code I can see **Service1** gets a request and calls `context.Respond(response);` but on the **Service2** side I always get a Timeout exception. Since, a message can make it from **Service2** to **Service1** I assume there are no network related issues. The timeout is pretty high as well. The message processing on **Service1** end takes less than a second. So I think a response message is just not routed properly and I don't understand why.  What is suspicious to me is that **SourceAddress** and **ResponseAddress** contain auto generated values and not `"CUSTOM_QUEUE_NAME?durable=false&autodelete=true&exclusive=false"`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you started the bus?

Comment: @Alexey Thank you, that was it. I tried many things but I couldn't think that a message can be sent with a non started bus for a Request method which is meant to be used for getting immediate response. I think it should have a check for a bus status and throw an exception. Thank you very much

Comment: You don't need to start the bus in order to send messages but you need to do it in order to receive messages, including responses.

Comment: Yes but Request method is meant to be used to send a request and get a response, at least the one I used in the question and it's very confusing when you can send a message with it but you get a timeout instead of an exception that a bus is not started

Comment: Sending request is possible if the bus is not started. MT connects to RMQ to receive messages when you start the bus, this is why you receive nothing and then it times out.

Comment: Correct, I'm just saying that this behavior is very confusing from Request method perspective

Answer (score 1):

You should start Bus, on your service start, like it shown [here](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#console-app)

```cs
await busControl.StartAsync(source.Token);
```